# RecyclerView Line above items

Tags: android

I have a `RecyclerView` with `Horizontal` and `Vertical` scrolling. Because, This is a Grid, with `recyclerview`. Why? Because It's much **optimalized** than simple `Grid` in `ScrollViews`.

I want to add a Line to recyclerview. Above the items. (Z coordinate)
[image]

This line need to scrolling with list items.

Anyone have idea how to do it?
Can I add a new Layer  above the items?

Comment: Add `headerView`.

Comment: The headerView is a new item, before real items. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably just add another view on top of the RecyclerView in the view hierarchy, add a ScrollListener to the RecyclerView and translate the line accordingly when the user scrolls.

```
<FrameLayout>

    <RecylerView
        ...
        />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/line"
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FF00FF"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Yes, It is a good idea. I will wait for other ideas. This is a little problematic

Comment: Thank you. Finally, I made by this idea. This is work really good.

Answer (score 1):

First of all create a vertical view like this : 
(in general the correct way is to declare the `View` first and position the list above this `View`) :

```
<View
android:layout_width="1dp"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />
```

And then declare your `<RecyclerView />`

N.B: if you have to use a simple layout, then use `FrameLayout` is more efficient, else use `RelativeLayout` (larger and more capable than the much simpler `FrameLayout`)

Comment: If I declare this view first, then it's behind the recycler. But It isn't scrolling with the recycler.